# Invalid syntax in model architecture in keras.layers

Tags: python, keras

Below is the code of a simple MLP but it's showing invalid syntax at the last line. How is it an error?

```
#model architecture
model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32*32),
                          keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
                          keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                          keras.layers.Dense(labels, activation='softmax')])
```

Attached image with error and code fragment.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnTiu.png)

Comment: Instead of "*thanks in advance*" and other irrelevant to the question stuff, please *post the error*.

Comment: sure. Suggestion noted and question updated.

Comment: The image you've attached and the code provided in the question are different. Please double check and add the error with proper formatting.

Comment: I will appreciate it if you help me debug it as you understood the question rather than decoration of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the shape of input in flatten layer, It will automatically convert the input into a 1d Row.

try:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
                  keras.layers.Flatten(),
                  keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                  keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
                  keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='relu'),
                  keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                  keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')])
```

Comment: After doing that also, throws the same error but now in the Flatten layer line.

Comment: But in a parallel model, I have passed the input_shape =(28*28), and that works pretty fine so what is the issue this time? I know that keras will automatically convert that into a 1D array. But what if i want to do hard coded way?

Comment: hey not sure about your parallel model code just try replace * with , like this keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32)

Answer (score 0):

The SyntaxError message can be quite misleading:

```
c:\a\bin>py toto.py 
  File "c:\a\bin\toto.py", line 8
keras.layers.Dense(labels, activation='softmax')])
                                                ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

(that's because the parser itself is somewhat confused) but it does point to a
*closing square bracket*, so this should tell you that you have a mis-matched
parenthesis somewhere. One way to get help is to ask your editor to **indent** the code. Emacs does it
like this:

```
#model architecture
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32*32),
                     keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                     keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
                     keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='relu'),
                     keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                     keras.layers.Dense(labels, activation='softmax')])
```

It puts the call to `keras.layers.Dense` at the same level as the `input_shape`
parameter, so clearly we're missing a parenthesis after
`input_shape=(32*32)`. Indenting again confirms that adding a parenthesis here fixes the problem:

```
#model architecture
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32*32)),
    keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.4),
    keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    keras.layers.Dense(labels, activation='softmax')])
```

Comment: Hi Joao, after doing it also didn't work. please see attached image with error.

Comment: @sonu, yes it did *"work"*: you asked about a syntax error, and adding the missing parenthesis fixed that syntax error. What your image shows is that your code now runs one step further, and you have another, completely different and unrelated, error: "'int' object is not iterable", because tuple() expects an iterable, not an int.